# Read multiple CSV files and replacing names

Tags: r, loops, csv, file, import

Suppose we have files *2021-02.csv, 2021-2.csv, ... , and 2021-12.csv* in directory **C:/R/month_data** and we want to read them all into separate data frames but replacing original names with months' names (eg. *2021-01.csv* should turn into "*jan*", *2021-02.csv* into "*feb*", ..., *2021-12.csv* into "*dec*").

The aim of the code is to have a total of 12 dfs.

I've written the following code:

```
filenames = list.files(path = "C:/R/month_data",
                       pattern = "2021-+.*csv")

names = substr(filenames,1,7)
months = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")

for(i in names){
  for (j in months){
    filepath = file.path("C:/R/month_data",paste(i,".csv",sep=""))
    assign(j, read.csv(filepath))
  }
}
```

The code technically runs but it doesn't associate the month number (eg. *2021-04*) with the rigth month name (eg. "*apr*")

What should I do?

Comment: If you file names are `2021-01.csv`, `2021-02.csv` your code should work fine.

Comment: Don't know why but it doesn't run...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to name each data frame you can read it into a list with `lapply` and rename the elements of the list. Now you can access the data frames in the list. Also, you can use the three-letter abbreviations for the English month names, `month.abb`.:

```
filenames = list.files(path = "C:/R/month_data/",
                       pattern = "2021-+.*csv")
filepath = paste0("C:/R/month_data/", filenames)

dfs <- lapply(filepath, read.csv)
names(dfs) <- month.abb

View(dfs$Jan)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a possible approach

```
library(data.table)
# get files to read
f <- list.files("c:/R/month_data/", pattern = "^2021-.*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
# destill months from filename
f.month <- month.abb[as.numeric(gsub("2021-(.*)\\.csv$", "\\1", basename(f)))]
#if you want month names based on a locale, you can use
# lubridate::month(
#   as.numeric(gsub("2021-(.*)\\.csv$", "\\1", basename(f))), 
#   label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)

# read the csv files
L <- lapply(f, data.table::fread)
# pass names to the list
names(L) <- f.month
# pass list's contents to the global environment
list2env(L, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `lubridate::month()` and `tidyr::nest()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# this is how I would read the file data, but because I don't have files, I will comment out
# filenames <- set_names(filenames, filenames)
# df <- map_dfr(filenames, read_csv, .id = "filename")

# and instead create simulated data at this point
df <- expand_grid(filename = c("2020-02.csv", "2021-02.csv", "2021-03.csv"), x = 1:5)

# parse the filename text to get a string for month name
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    dttm = filename %>% 
      str_remove(".csv") %>% 
      str_split("-", simplify = FALSE) %>%
      map_chr(~str_c(.[2], "1", .[1], sep = "-")) %>%
      mdy(),
    mnth = month(dttm, label = TRUE),
    new_filename = str_c(mnth, ".csv")
  )
print(df)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#>    filename        x dttm       mnth  new_filename
#>    <chr>       <int> <date>     <ord> <chr>       
#>  1 2020-02.csv     1 2020-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#>  2 2020-02.csv     2 2020-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#>  3 2020-02.csv     3 2020-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#>  4 2020-02.csv     4 2020-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#>  5 2020-02.csv     5 2020-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#>  6 2021-02.csv     1 2021-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#>  7 2021-02.csv     2 2021-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#>  8 2021-02.csv     3 2021-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#>  9 2021-02.csv     4 2021-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#> 10 2021-02.csv     5 2021-02-01 Feb   Feb.csv     
#> 11 2021-03.csv     1 2021-03-01 Mar   Mar.csv     
#> 12 2021-03.csv     2 2021-03-01 Mar   Mar.csv     
#> 13 2021-03.csv     3 2021-03-01 Mar   Mar.csv     
#> 14 2021-03.csv     4 2021-03-01 Mar   Mar.csv     
#> 15 2021-03.csv     5 2021-03-01 Mar   Mar.csv

# now, one row per month with columns new_filename and data (list of tibbles)
df <- df %>%
  select(-c(filename, dttm, mnth)) %>%
  nest(data = -new_filename) 
print(df)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   new_filename data             
#>   <chr>        <list>           
#> 1 Feb.csv      <tibble [10 x 1]>
#> 2 Mar.csv      <tibble [5 x 1]>

# write files
df %>%
  with(
    walk2(data, new_filename, write_csv)
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>