# Read all files in directory and assign names from list

Tags: r, purrr

I have a directory with a set number of data files in it. I would like to read each file into my workspace as a separate object and assign each one a name from a pre-defined list. So instead of...

```
data_a <- read_csv('data/file_1.csv')
data_b <- read_csv('data/file_2.csv')
```

...and so on, I would like something like...

```
data_files_list <- here('data') %>% list.files()
data_files_list
[1] "file_1.csv" "file_2.csv"

filename_list <- c('data_a', 'data_b')
?????
```

...but I can't work out what `?????` should be.

I *really* want it to be something like `purrr:walk2(filename_list, data_files_list, assign)` but that doesn't work. I've found a few other questions similar to mine but not quite the same, and I haven't been able to adapt them to my needs.

Can anyone provide me with a solution, very ideally using `tidyverse` (because it fits well with the rest of my workflow)? I would also be very grateful for an explanation of *how* the solution works, especially if you can show me what the underlying `for()` loop (or whatever) is. Although I enjoy the streamlined writing of `purrr` I also find them opaque and struggle to understand what's happening under the hood.

(Note that I'm using the `here` library to make file paths but I don't care if the solution uses `here` or a more traditional method.)

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71557209/5325862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read them all into a named list object like so:

```r
library(purrr)

l_df <- map(set_names(data_files_list, filename_list), read.csv)
```

You can then assign the list elements to an environment using `list2env(l_df)`, but this is generally not advised (list elements may conflict with objects in the environment, R has a lot of list functionality, etc.).

Comment: I modified your answer for my final solution: `list.files('./data', full.names=TRUE) |>  map(read_csv) |> setNames(c('data_a', 'data_b')) |> list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)`. The entire approach has some obvious flaws regarding file directory structure but it's what I'm looking for. I hear you on `list2env` but the csvs have very different structures and functions so it's conceptually easier to treat them as different objects than to keep them as a list of dataframes.